# sum of reciprocal arithmetic progression is not an integer with negative term.

Tags: number-theory

I already find the fact sum of reciprocal arithmetic progression with only positive term can't be integer. In the following $a<d$ be positive integer with $\left(a,\,d\right)=1$.

$\sum_{0\le k\le n} \frac{1}{ak+d}\notin\mathbb{Z}$

But I'm interested in general case with negative term. Simple observation makes the constraint $\left|d\right|\ne 2$.

$\sum_{-m\le k\le n} \frac{1}{ak+d}\notin\mathbb{Z}$??????

Is there any result about this?

Comment: Since $$\sum_{-m\le k\le n} \frac{1}{ak+d} = \sum_{0\le k\le n + m}\frac{1}{ak + (d-am)}$$ the answer will depend on how critical the condition that $a < d$ is. If the expression is also not integer when $a > d$, then it will not be integer for your expression either. If there are examples where $a > d$ and the sum is integer, then it is not guaranteed that your sum will also have examples, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct corollary of Shorey and Tijdeman's 1990 result (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511983917.032)), which states that the largest prime divisor in $k$ consecutive terms in an arithmetical progression is at least $k+1$ for $k\geq 2$ except for the arithmetical progression $2,9,16$. In particular, it is only needed that the largest prime divisor in $k$ terms $\geq k$.

Moreover, there is another more elementary [proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/152296/131145) that only relies on Bertrand–Chebyshev theorem.

As for the Erdős 1932 [proof](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1932-02.pdf), an English exposition is posted on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311452/602219) site.