# For which integers $a\gt 0, b\ge 0$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{ak+b}$ never an integer for $n > 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

For which integers $a\gt 0, b\ge 0$ is
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{ak+b}$
never an integer for $n > 1$?

This is inspired
by a number of cases where this is true
($(a, b)
=(1, 0),
(3, 1)
$).

It might be feasible
do consider the cases when
$a$ and $b$
are relatively prime,
but I don't even see how to
attack these.

Even though
I don't see how to begin
answering this
for restricted classes
of $a$ and $b$,
I thought this was
interesting enough
to propose.

Comment: The case where $a$ and $b$ are coprime that you mention was proven by Erdős, as discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2310781/695196).

Comment: And when the non-coprime case reduces to the coprime case: $\sum_{k} \frac{1}{ak+b} = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{k} \frac{1}{a'k+b'}$ where $d=\text{gcd}(a,b)$, $1=\text{gcd}(a',b')$.